# Rails simple_form: Prevent labels from wrapping input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I am unsure with some of the configuration options of simple_form in a Rails application: I am using the enum_help plugin https://github.com/zmbacker/enum_help and I display an enum as radio button options.

However the HTML generated wraps radio buttons inside the labels; I would like to have the inputs (radio buttons) first, then the labels.
Current output:

```
  <!-- this is the "label" that seems to be reacting to b.label in the simple form initializer - see below -->
  <label class="enum_radio_buttons optional">Rating</label>
  <span class="radio radio radio">
    <label for="book_rating_favourite">
      <input class="enum_radio_buttons optional" type="radio" value="favourite" name="book[rating]" id="book_rating_favourite" />
      Favourite
    </label>
  </span>
  <span class="radio radio radio">
    ...
  </span>
  ...
```

Desired output:

```
  <label class="enum_radio_buttons optional">Rating</label>
  <span class="radio radio radio">
    <input class="enum_radio_buttons optional" type="radio" value="favourite" name="book[rating]" id="book_rating_favourite" />
    <label for="book_rating_favourite">
      Favourite
    </label>
  </span>
  <span class="radio radio radio">
    ...
  </span>
  ...
```

I am not quite sure what to do to change this behavior...

**EDIT:**

I tried to define a custom wrapper but that doesn't seem to work. The "label" is referring to the label of the full radio button group (edited code above for clarity), and so while I was able to change the order and have input first, and label second, the only thing that happened was that the title was BELOW the radio buttons.

Here's the relevant part of config/initializers/simple_form.rb; it seems that b.use :input simply renders the input nested within the individual label...

```
  config.wrappers :enum_radio,
   hint_class: :field_with_hint, error_class: :field_with_errors, valid_class: :field_without_errors do |b|
    # we need the radio button first, and then the label
    # the label should not wrap the button
    b.use :html5
    b.use :placeholder
    b.use :input

    # copied from :default wrapper
    b.use :hint,  wrap_with: { tag: :span, class: :hint }
    b.use :error, wrap_with: { tag: :span, class: :error }
  end
```

And here is how I try to use it in the form:

```
  <%= simple_form_for book do |f| %>
    <%= render 'shared/form_errors', form: f %>
    ...
      <div class="form-col">
        <%= f.input :rating, as: :radio_buttons, wrapper: :enum_radio %>
      </div>
    ...
  <% end %>
```

Comment: Please post the rails code too, not just the rendered HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`EnumHelp` yields to `SimpleForm`](https://github.com/zmbacker/enum_help/blob/master/lib/enum_help/simple_form.rb#L16)

So, you'll have to do some `SimpleForm` customization to achieve this.

Check out [custom wrappers](https://github.com/heartcombo/simple_form/wiki/Custom-Wrappers) as a starting point.

Comment: that's it - thanks I will have a look!

Comment: unfortunately, while this for sure is the place to try - it didn't work. See above for more, I altered the question. Essentially, I don't seem to be able to define a custom wrapper that takes the individual inputs and labels apart. More context above...

Comment: Can you turn off the labels for `f.input :ratings` all together? I think it's just `label: false` for standard fields.

Comment: If I do that, the first label (the "title" of the group) disappears. I am starting to believe that the enum_help causes more confusion than it helps...

Comment: Yeah, could be more problems than solutions. However, if you can remove the labels and that gets rid of the wrapper, you could add labels with JS on page load.